# Getting date time in Azure DevOps yml and concat a version number with it

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml

I have the following yml. What I'm attempting to do is to create a version number based on several other variables (`version.Major`, `version.Minor`, `versionDay`, and `BuildNumber`). But the set variable powershell task isn't overwriting the initial values for versionday, so the output of versionNumber in my echo script below would be like: `1.0.set below.2021037.6` Any ideas? Syntax issues I'm not seeing?

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop, 
      - sprint/*
      - Sprint/*

pool:
  name: 'MyCustomAgent'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  version.Major: '1'
  version.Minor: '0',
  versionDay: 'set below'
  versionNumber: 'set dynamically'

steps:
- script: |
    echo: $(Build.SourceBranch)

- powershell: |
      if ("$(Build.SourceBranch)".Contains('sprint')) {
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildConfiguration;]Release"
        [string] $currentMonthDay= (Get-Date -Format 'MMdd')
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=versionDay]$currentMonthDay"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=versionNumber]$(version.Major).$(version.Minor).$(versionDay)"

      } else {
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildConfiguration;]Debug"
        [string] $currentMonthDay= (Get-Date -Format 'MMdd')
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=versionDay]$currentMonthDay"
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=versionNumber]$(version.Major).$(version.Minor).$(versionDay).$(Build.BuildNumber)"
      }      

- script: | 
    echo building configuration $(buildConfiguration)
    echo $(versionDay)
    echo $(versionNumber)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the variables as output - note the change to your `setvariable` statements below:

```yaml
pool:
  name: 'MyCustomAgent'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  version.Major: '1'
  version.Minor: '0',
  versionDay: 'set below'
  versionNumber: 'set dynamically'

steps:
- script: |
    echo: $(Build.SourceBranch)

- powershell: |
      # note the use of ;isOutput=true in setvariable commands
      if ("$(Build.SourceBranch)".Contains('sprint')) {
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildConfiguration;]Release"
        [string] $currentMonthDay= (Get-Date -Format 'MMdd')
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=versionDay]$currentMonthDay"
        # You can't use $(versionDay) here as setvariable is for subsequent steps/jobs/stages
        # use its calculated value instead
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=versionNumber]$(version.Major).$(version.Minor).$($currentMonthDay)"

      } else {
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildConfiguration;isOutput=true]Debug"
        [string] $currentMonthDay= (Get-Date -Format 'MMdd')
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=versionDay;isOutput=true]$currentMonthDay"
        # You can't use $(versionDay) here as setvariable is for subsequent steps/jobs/stages
        # use its calculated value instead
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=versionNumber;isOutput=true]$(version.Major).$(version.Minor).$($currentMonthDay).$(Build.BuildNumber)"
      }      

- script: | 
    echo building configuration $(buildConfiguration)
    echo $(versionDay)
    echo $(versionNumber)
```